# AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objs' has no attribute 'pie'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

temp = train_data['project_is_approved'].value_counts()
labels = temp.index
sizes = (temp/temp.sum())*100
trace = go.pie(labels=labels,values=sizes,hoverinfo='label+percent')
layout = go.Layout(title='project proposal is approved or not')
data = [trace]
fig = go.figure(data = data,layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

When run, this code fails with the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objs' has no attribute 'pie'
```

Comment: According to the [Docs](https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/), it is `Pie` (with a capital P) not `pie`. Just change that

Answer (score 1):

You can also try getting ploty charts from pandas dataframe using cufflinks.

This may help u:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
d = {'project_is_approved':[5,20,5,69,14,5,69,14,69,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['temp'] = df.groupby('project_is_approved', as_index=False)['project_is_approved'].transform(lambda s: s.count())
sizes = (df.temp/df.temp.sum())*100
df.insert(loc=2,column = 'sizes',value=sizes)
df.iplot(kind='pie',values='sizes', labels=['project_is_approved','temp'],textposition='outside',hoverinfo='label+percent',title='project proposal is approved or not')
```